# How to set button to the bottom of the screen in ionic 2 application

Tags: button, ionic-framework, alignment

Trying to fix a button to the bottom of the screen in ionic 2 application, but  i don't know why it is taking a space after button. I have tried alot of method even have changes the main.css regarding the button, but not able to fix it. Please help, I want to stick it to the bottom with no space[image].

Code i am using for:

```html
</ion-content>
<ion-footer no-padding style="margin:0rem 0rem!Important;">
  <button ion-button block color="Dark" (click)="pushPage()">Explore</button>
  </ion-footer>
```

`<ion-footer>` is kept outside of the `<ion-content>`, so as to make the button fixed on scrolling.Even on removing 'margin' and 'no-padding' no effect is found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In app.scss(or in relative .scss) add the following code:

```
.footer{
    button{
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach will be to use [Ionic CSS utilities](https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities) and do not touch `app.scss` at all.

```html
<ion-footer class="ion-no-padding ion-no-margin">
  <ion-button class="ion-no-margin" block color="Dark" (click)="pushPage()">Explore</ion-button>
</ion-footer>
```